# Angular transclude and scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to generate a directive for click-to-edit input fields. Since I have a variety of different types of input fields that it needs to work with, I wanted to make it an attribute type directive that just transcludes the input field itself.

However, the problem is that when using a scope parameter to the directive description (for ipDisable), things stop working as they should (try commenting in line 44 in jsFiddle js part). Presumably, it is therefore a scope error, but I really have no idea where to begin debugging it, and any help would be appreciated.

jsFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/HbYwX/3/

HTML:

```
<input inplace type="string" ip-disable=false name="username" ng-model="uname">
```

JS:

```
myApp.directive('inplace', function($compile) {

var compile = function(tElem,tAttrib,transclude) {

  var whole = $('<div ng-scope></div>');

  var editable = $('<div class="editable-transclude" ng-hide="static">'+
                  '<a ng-click="changeStatic()" ng-show="!static && !disable()">'+
                  '&ltsave&gt</a></div>');

  whole.append(editable).append('<span class="disabledText" ng-show="static">{{ngModel.$viewValue}}</span>' +
            '<a ng-click="changeStatic()" ng-show="static && !disable()">'+
            '&ltedit&gt</a>');

  tElem.replaceWith(whole);

  transclude(tElem,function(clone) {
    clone.removeAttr('inplace');
    editable.prepend(clone);
  });  

  return function(scope, element, attrs) {  

    var input_element = $($(element).find('input')[0]);
    scope.name = input_element.name;
    scope.ngModel = element.controller('ngModel');

    scope.static = true;

    scope.changeStatic = function() {
      if (scope.static) {
        scope.static = false;
      } else if (!scope.ngModel.$error[scope.name]){
        scope.static = true;
      }
    };
  };
};

return {
  transclude: 'element',
  scope: { disable: '&ipDisable' },
  restrict: 'A',
  compile: compile
};  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ed's proposed solution solved a part of the problem. However, there was another one that probably threw me off in the first place:

The template was compiled into the parent scope as opposed to being attached to the new directive scope. To fix that, I needed to manually compile the created template in the linker function, where I could bind it to the proper scope.

The working solution is:
http://jsfiddle.net/HbYwX/5/

```
 myApp.directive('inplace', function($compile) {

var compile = function(tElem,tAttrib,transclude) {

  var whole = $('<div ng-scope></div>');

    var editable = $('<div class="editable-transclude" ng-hide="static">'+
                  '<a ng-click="changeStatic()" ng-show="!static && ipDisable()">'+
                  '&ltsave&gt</a></div>');

  transclude(tElem,function(clone) {
    clone.removeAttr('inplace');
    clone.attr('ng-model','model');
    editable.prepend(clone);
  });

  whole.append(editable).append('<span class="disabledText" ng-show="static">{{model}}</span>' +
            '<a ng-click="changeStatic()" ng-show="static && !ipDisable()">'+
            '&ltedit&gt</a>');


  return function(scope, element, attrs) {

    element.replaceWith($compile(whole)(scope));

    scope.name = attrs.name;

    scope.static = true;

    scope.changeStatic = function() {
      if (scope.static) {
        scope.static = false;
      } else {
        scope.static = true;
        if (scope.name) scope.$emit('inplace-edit',scope.name);
      }
    };
  };
};

return {
  transclude: 'element',
  scope: { ipDisable: '&', model: '=' },
  restrict: 'A',
  compile: compile
};  
});
```

(which might be useful to anyone looking for something similar and is under MIT licence i.e. do what you wish with it).

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're moving the `input` element inside an element that has an isolate scope, so it can no-longer interact with the scope outside of it. As such, the `uname` you have bound to will not be on the same scope as the one you're feeding into the `ng-model` of the input.

You've got a couple of options - the first is not to create the isolate scope at all - you can still access `ipDisable` through `attrs` in your link function.

The other (better) solution, is to add `ngModel` to the isolate scope as well (`scope: { disable: '&ipDisable', ngModel:'='}`,), and update the value of the input yourself using the [ngModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController), when the input is changed.

Comment: I briefly tried the first possiblity on myown and could not quite make it work (I would have to $watch the attribute in question, right?).
The better solution sounds fairly complicated too, unless I'm missing something. Is there a reasonably easy way to bind the whole-directive ng-model directly to the input fields ng-model, or do I have to hand wire all the API calls?